# Create a function to generate random points in a parallelogram

Tags: function, lua

I hope someone can help me here, I have been asked to write some code for an Lua script for a game. Firstly i am not an Lua Scripter and I am defiantly no mathematician.

What i need to do is generate random points within a parallelogram, so over time the entire parallelogram becomes filled. I have played with the scripting and had some success with the parallelogram (rectangle) positioned on a straight up and down or at 90 degrees. My problem comes when the parallelogram is rotated.

As you can see in the image, things are made even worse by the coordinates originating at the centre of the map area, and the parallelogram can be positioned anywhere within the map area. The parallelogram itself is defined by 3 pairs of coordinates, start_X and Start_Y, Height_X and Height_Y and finally Width_X and Width_Y. The random points generated need to be within the bounds of these coordinates regardless of position or orientation.

[Map coordinates and example parallelogram](http://www.ic.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/Parralalagram.gif)

An example of coordinates are...

Start_X = 122.226
Start_Y = -523.541

Height_X = 144.113
Height_Y = -536.169

Width_X = 128.089
Width_Y = -513.825

In my script testing i have eliminated the decimals down to .5 as any smaller seems to have no effect on the final outcome. Also in real terms the start width and height could be in any orientation when in final use.

Is there anyone out there with the patients to explain what i need to do to get this working, my maths is pretty basic, so please be gentle.

Thanks for reading and in anticipation of a reply.
Ian

Answer (score 0):

In Pseudocode

```
a= random number with 0<=a<=1
b= random number with 0<=b<=1
x= Start_X + a*(Width_X-Start_X) + b*(Height_X-Start_X)
y= Start_Y + a*(Width_Y-Start_Y) + b*(Height_Y-Start_Y)
```

this should make a random point at coordinates x,y within the parallelogram

The idea is that each point inside the parallelogram can be specified by saying how far you go from Start in the direction of the first edge (a) and how far you go in the direction of the second edge (b).

For example, if you have a=0, and b=0, then you do not move at all and are still at Start.
If you have a=1, and b=0, then you move to Width.
If you have a=1, and b=1, then you move to the opposite corner.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your reply but i was not blessed with a math head at birth and i am confused with the first two lines.

Are you saying the a and b can be either 0 or 1, or do i need to generate a random number between the coordinate values like between start_x and height_x. In all honesty i don't get the 0<=a<=1 bit, could you please explain.

Comment: You need to generate a random number for a that can be any number in the range 0.0 to 1.0 (e.g. 0.0 0.23,0.7, etc.)  There is usually a standard function to do this for you called something like math.random()

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like "texture coordinates", which are in the range `[0,1]`, to generate X,Y for a point inside your parallelogram. Then, you could generate random numbers `(u,v)` from range `[0,1]` and get a random point you want.

To explain this better, here is a picture:

[image]

The base is formed by vectors `v1` and `v2`. The four points `A,B,C,D` represent the corners of the parallelogram. You can see the "texture coordinates" (which I will call `u,v`) of the points in parentheses, for example `A` is `(0,0)`, `D` is `(1,1)`. Every point inside the parallelogram will have coordinates within `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`, for example the center of the parallelogram has coordinates `(0.5,0.5)`.

To get the vectors `v1,v2`, you need to do vector subtraction: `v1 = B - A`, `v2 = C - A`. When you generate random coordinates `u,v` for a random point `r`, you can get back the X,Y using this vector formula: `r = A + u*v1 + v*v2`.

In Lua, you can do this as follows:

```
 -- let's say that you have A,B,C,D defined as the four corners as {x=...,y=...}
 -- (actually, you do not need D, as it is D=v1+v2)

 -- returns the vector a+b
 function add(a,b)
   return {x = a.x + b.x, y = a.y + b.y} end
 end
 -- returns the vector a-b
 function sub(a,b)
   return {x = a.x - b.x, y = a.y - b.y} end
 end
 -- returns the vector v1*u + v2*v
 function combine(v1,u,v2,v)
   return {x = v1.x*u + v2.x*v, y = v1.y*u + v2.y*v}
 end
 -- returns a random point in parallelogram defined by 2 vectors and start
 function randomPoint(s,v1,v2)
   local u,v = math.random(), math.random() -- these are in range [0,1]
   return add(s, combine(v1,u,v2,v))
 end

 v1 = sub(B,A) -- your basis vectors v1, v2
 v2 = sub(C,A)
 r = randomPoint(A,v1,v2) -- this will be in your parallelogram defined by A,B,C
```

Note that this will not work with your current layout - start, width, height. How do you want to handle rotation with these parameters?